# how do i remove content from magento sidebar

Tags: php, magento

I did not found a way to remove existing content from magento sidebar and to add my own content.

How do I do this?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the "`page.xml`" (located in "`app/design/frontend/<your_package_name>/<your_theme_name>/layout/`" folder) to have only "`1column.phtml`" template, instead of other possible templates (like "`2columns-left.phtml`", "`2columns-right.phtml`", "`3columns.phtml`").

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: [Intro to Layouts](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts) for an introduction, and then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069246/magento-store-remove-block-using-update-xml) for a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

Also look at the site of alanstorm, http://alanstorm.com/category/magento , he got very useful tutorials. At the beginning, magento is quite complicated.