# Magento - Remove js of search catalog page

Tags: javascript, magento, search, catalog

How do I remove js only of search catalog page?

I've tried use this code in catalogsearch.xml with reference name="head"...

```
<action method="removeItem">
    <type>skin_js</type>
    <name>slideshowwidget/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js</name>
</action>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2069932/1163653

Answer (score 0):

If your js file is located in the Magento root js dir you should use "js" as type instead of "skin_js":

```
<action method="removeItem">
    <type>js</type>
    <name>slideshowwidget/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js</name>
</action>
```

Comment: I already got it with the same code in a different place, but with your code will not work, because my file is in skin