# Removing a static block from a specific page (XML Update)

Tags: xml, magento

I would like to remove a static block that is called on every page from one specific page.

Currently in my header.phtml I have this code...

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

This displays the contents of my topmenu.phtml file which contains the following code...

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('newnav')->toHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('further-menu')->toHtml() ?>
```

I would like to remove the static block 'further-menu' from displaying in a particular page by using the XML update page.

So far I have tried many methods such as below but to little avail.

```
<reference name="top.menu">
<block type="cms/block" name="further-menu">
<action method="unsetChild"><name>further-menu</name></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove any block from xml using

```
<remove name="BLOCK NAME"/>
```

Comment: I have already tried this and it doesn't seem to work, just to clarify I used this code.

    `<remove name="further-menu"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [Magento Store - Remove Block using Update XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069246/magento-store-remove-block-using-update-xml)

```
<reference name="top.menu">
   <remove name="further-menu"/>
</reference>
```

You may want to enable developer mode to double check that you are using the correct blocks

Answer (score 0):

Goto CMS Pages

Open page in which you don't want to display block goto Display tab add following code in Layout Update XML Box.

`<reference name="top.menu">
   <remove name="further-menu"/>
</reference>`